# Image loads after 1 second

Tags: java, graphics2d

For some reason my image loads after 1 second even though I call render before my thread.sleep ()

```
public void init (){
    image=new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g= (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    running=true;
}

public void run (){
    init();

    while(running){
        long start=System.nanoTime();
        update();
        render();   
        drawToScreen();

        try{
            thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void update (){

}

public void render (){
    g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for(int r=0; r<16; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<16; c++){
            MazeCell m=maze[15-r][c];
            int y=15-m.getRow();
            int x=m.getCol();




            if(m.getWallUp()) g.drawLine(x*50, y*50, (x+1)*50, y*50);
            if(m.getWallDown()) g.drawLine(x*50, (y+1)*50, (x+1)*50, (y+1)*50);
            if(m.getWallLeft()) g.drawLine(x*50, y*50, x*50, (y+1)*50);
            if(m.getWallRight()) g.drawLine((x+1)*50, y*50, (x+1)*50, (y+1)*50);
        }
    }

    g.drawImage(mouseImage, mouse.getCol()*50, (15-mouse.getRow())*50, null);

}

public void drawToScreen (){
    Graphics g2=getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage (image, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Everything draws but at first there is a blank gray screen and it only loads after 1 second (the time the thread sleeps) even though render and drawToScreen are called first. I don't really know the reason.

Comment: You've omitted quite a bit of important stuff, like the declaration and initialization of `g`, the declaration of `getGraphics()`, etc. and any description of troubleshooting you've already done.

Comment: You are sleeping the same thread that draws the picture. It takes time to draw an image, it doesn't just happen immediately in one line

Comment: cricket_007...that is what I thought initially. DO you have a suggestion to wait for the thread to finish drawing the image before the sleep is called.

Comment: I put the initialization of g. getGraphics() is a function inherited from JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Change your:

```
g2.dispose();
```

To:

```
g2.finalize();
```

Also, the description of the Graphics.drawImage() method states:

> Draws as much of the specified image as is currently available. The image is drawn with its top-left corner at (x, y) in this graphics context's coordinate space. Transparent pixels in the image do not affect whatever pixels are already there.
>   This method returns immediately in all cases, even if the complete image has not yet been loaded, and it has not been dithered and converted for the current output device.
>
> If the image has completely loaded and its pixels are no longer being changed, then drawImage returns true. Otherwise, drawImage returns false and as more of the image becomes available or it is time to draw another frame of animation, the process that loads the image notifies the specified image observer.

In other words, the call returns immediately, whether or not the image drawing has completed.

You can use MediaTracker to first make sure the image is loaded before you call Graphics.drawImage():

```
       long timeout = 60000;  // 60 seconds
       MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
       tracker.addImage(image, 0);
       try {
         if (!tracker.waitForID( 0, timeout ) ) {
           System.out.println( "Timed Out!" );
           return;
         }
       } 
       catch( Exception ex) {
         System.out.println( "Error waiting for the image to load." );
         return;
       }

       boolean isFinished = g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
```